# Does flatpak uninstall have purge option like apt

Tags: flatpak

Does `flatpak` have a uninstallation "purge" option like `apt`?

Purpose: to uninstall an app, *and all config files*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When flatpak removes an app, it removes the entire sandbox directory so everything related to the app is removed. This doesn’t include home directory config files of course, but apt doesn’t do that either.

Comment: Thanks. By "home directory config files" do you mean those for the app, or for flatpak itself?

Comment: Files that would appear in ~/.config, ~/.cache, etc.

Comment: Then I assume that means user config is kept, but app config from `/etc/flatpak` (or wherever) is removed. Pity there's no purge option to blast away everything flatpak-related. I take your point about apt though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I try it and it works, what you have to do in the command line(Bash) is:

1. Type just

   ```shell
   flatpak list --app
   ```
2. In the column "Application ID" look for the app you want to purge. Then type

   ```shell
   flatpak uninstall --delete-data Application_ID
   ```

   and follow the instructions.

**Example:**

I want to purge Clementine app.

- I type `flatpak list -app` and I see the `Application_ID` from that app is `org.clementine_player.Clementine`.
- Then I type

  ```shell
  flatpak uninstall --delete-data org.clementine_player.Clementine
  ```

  and follow the instructions.